# jQuery ajax Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

All of the posts I've read on this question are because the object being passed contains other objects, instead of primitive values.

My data object is all primitive values and yet it still doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
function ImageUploader(imgEl, params) {
    this.imgEl = imgEl;
    this.params = params;
    this.params["Function"] = "saveImage";
}

// send data from asynchronously uploaded image (as image URI)
// to PHP script which will write data to file
ImageUploader.prototype.uploadImage = function () {
    var iu = this;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function (e) {
        iu.params["Image"] = e.target.result;
        console.log(iu.params);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/scripts/php/Form.php",
            data: iu.params,
            success: alert,
            error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                console.log(error, this);
            }
        });
    };

    this.params["FileName"] = this.imgEl.files[0].fileName || this.imgEl.files[0].name;
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.imgEl.files[0]);
};
```

Here's an example object that it rejects:

```
{
  FileName: "Matrix.jpg",
  Function: "saveImage",
  ID: 10,
  Image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,...",
  Line: 1,
  Name: "Test Form"
}
```

Comment: Your issue is probably the `success: alert` line.  Why are you doing that?  Try doing `success: function(data){ alert(data); }`

Comment: @RocketHazmat You were right, but that's kind of weird because it worked fine that way before. They should be equivalent. Anyways, thank you.

Comment: @KthProg: Host-provided functions are not necessarily real functions, cross-browser. Generally best to wrap them.

Comment: It should *never* have worked that way.  The `success` function is called in the "context" of the `jqXHR` object (`success.call(jqXHR, data,...)`), and `alert()` needs to be called in the context of `window`.

Comment: The context was almost always window when I previously used it... that must have been a convenient coincidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with your `iu.params` object.  The error is with this line:

```
success: alert,
```

The `window.alert()` (or just `alert()`) function needs to be called in the "context" of the `window` object.

When you do `success: alert`, jQuery calls the success callback in the contect of the jqXHR object that ran the AJAX request.  Something like this:

```
success.call(jqXHR, data)
```

<sub>I don't know the *exact* code jQuery uses</sub>

So, your `alert` is being called in the wrong "context", so it's throwing an error.  To fix it, just pass an anonymous function to `success`:

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
}
```

Or, if you *really* want to, you can use `.bind()` to make sure `alert()` is called in the right context:

```
success: alert.bind(window)
```

If you *really* *really* want to keep `success: alert`, then you can tell jQuery to call it in the right context, by adding `context: window` to your `$.ajax` call.

Be warned that `alert.bind()` (and, in turn `context: window`) might not work in all browsers, and therefore is *not* suggested.  I'd suggest you use the anonymous function as shown instead.

Comment: *"Or, if you really want to, you can use `.bind()` to make sure `alert()` is called in the right context"* That won't necessarily work properly cross-browser: host-provided functions are not required to support `bind` (or `call`, `apply`, and other `Function.prototype` things).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Really?  I do know that host objects are weird, but I figured that'd work.  I mean, the *correct* solution is to wrap it in a anonymous function, but I was trying to add alternatives :-)

Comment: $ Rocket: Yup, really. For instance, `alert.call(window, "foo");` fails in IE8, because `alert` doesn't have `call` or `apply` (and if you shim `Function.prototype.bind`, `alert` still won't doesn't have it, because it's not a true function and doesn't inherit from `Function.prototype`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: *Everything* fails in IE8!  Is that still a problem, though?  Do *modern* browsers support `alert.bind()`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Anyway, I'll add a note into the answer about that, it's a pretty good point.

Comment: @ Rocket: IE9 does, and obviously recent Chrome and Firefox. I don't know about the various Android browsers (I wouldn't bet on 2.x). But remember that IE8 still has [nearly 20% global market share](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0), thanks to all the XP users who refuse to upgrade, or even install Chrome/Firefox. :-) Of course, the only stats that matter are the stats for one's *own* site, but...

Comment: @ Rocket: You've made me laugh there, btw, because in answers these days I say things like "`querySelectorAll` is supported in all modern browsers, and also IE8". ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I had to deal with IE8 (and once even IE7, it was horrible) at work (I'm a webdev).  I'm ***so*** glad my boss said we're only supporting IE9+ from now on.  Though, I still have my Windows XP VM set up...  just in case.

Comment: @ Rocket: I'll date myself when I say that I remember when we were all so happy IE6 came out and really moved the web forward. :-) We had no idea that would be it (from MS) for a *decade*...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I remember using Netscape Navigator (version 4, I think)! :-D  Thing is, IE6 *did* actually add some new technologies!  Problem was that Microsoft - while once the innovator - took *forever* to release a new browser and when they did they were so far behind and couldn't catch up :-P